# arrange element bottom to top using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am trying to arrange DOM elements display order bottom to top.But not able to find the way to do it. I am beginner in CSS. Please help me resolve this.It is a dynamic DOM generated by JS so can't change HTML.

e.g:

```
<div>
   <img src='abc.jpg'>
   <a href='google.com'>Google</a>
   <p >It is google</p>
</div>
```

Expected Result:

```
  <div> 
    <p >It is google</p>
    <a href='google.com'>Google</a>
     <img src='abc.jpg'>
  </div>
```

or:

```
<div> 
   <a href='google.com'>Google</a>
    <p >It is google</p>
     <img src='abc.jpg'>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you show me example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 div { 
   display: flex; 
   flex-flow:wrap;
 }
 img{
  order: 3;
  flex-basis: 100%;
 }
 a {
   order: 2;
   flex-basis: 100%;
 }
 p {
   order:1 ;
   flex-basis: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox:
http://jsbin.com/mesijerike

```
div {
 width: 200px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

Comment: It is almost what I am searching for. But what if I want 2nd at top, then third in middle and first bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put these flex box css in your parent div

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
```